# Check if parameter is present in url with multiple ones

Tags: php, cookies, parameters

I need to check if there's a parameter in URL and add a cookie.
I wrote something like this but it only works when my url has only that parameter.

```
if (isset($_GET['parameter'])) {
    setcookie('cookie', $_GET['parameter'], time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
}
```

example
domain.com?parameter=xyxyx -->> WORKS

domain.com?parameter=xyxyx&gclid=iajhsidjaisdjd  -->> NOT WORKING

what's wrong with my code? I would like it to work always for any parameter after/before

thanks

Comment: `$_GET['parameter']` doesn't care about the position/order of the parameter

Comment: weird, so what could be the reason it does not work when there are more than 1 parameter?

Comment: Not sure. How did you debug this, just by checking if the cookie is set? For testing, simply `echo "yes"` if it is set and `echo "no"` if it is not set. This should work for `?parameter=xyxyx&gclid=iajhsidjaisdjd` as well as `?gclid=iajhsidjaisdjd&parameter=xyxyx`

Comment: Maybe you can do a `var_dump($_GET)` to see what you receive in the `$_GET`. Maybe a typo somewhere is all that needs to be corrected